# Visual Studio authentication issue with SharePoint app

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, visual-studio

I am working on a SharePoint app in visual studio and am running into issues when attempting to debug.

I press start and as expected the Connect to SharePoint window pops up asking me for my credentials. I enter them and attempt to proceed but instead of continuing to the debug site it goes to the root web of the site in the Connect to SharePoint window and freezes.

What could be causing this? What can I do to resolve it?

Edit: It was working ~two weeks ago when I last worked on this project but since I came back to it yesterday it won't let me debug.

[image: Authentication screen issue]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the project name in solution explorer and press F4 key, It will open project property.

Go to site Url property and then erase old property and write your office 365 base url like https://xyz.sharepoint.com press tab and save solution, it will open new authentication window. Enter credentials and click on log in.

Comment: The site URL is already pointing to the correct site. I checked it and when prompted entered my credentials again but had the same result as above. It seems my Visual Studio can't communicate with the SharePoint server for some reason.

Comment: Please check url contains https:// and second check app catalog is available in that site, if some one deleted app catalog then it may cause problem.

Comment: The url is contains the https:// and the app catalog is available on the root site

Comment: may be create a new dev site would be easier

Comment: I tried with one of my colleagues dev sites and ran into the same issue. He was still able to debug on it without running into the issue